# Numerical Approximation Values Exceed Exact Value

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

Is it possible for the numerical approximation (Euler, Improved Euler,or Runge-Kutta) to both exceed and fall under the exact value of a first order differential equation?

Answer (score 2):

For example, for the differential equation $y' = k y$, $y(0) = y_0$ with $k > 0$, the Euler approximation is less than the exact value if $y_0 > 0$, greater than the exact value if $y_0 < 0$.